# How to do port forwarding in D-link Glb802c?

Tags: port-forwarding

I have some questions about port forwarding on my D-Link Router GLB-802C.

For example:

- My local machine's IP is `117.1.1.81`
- My router's IP is `117.1.1.1`
- My Public (Web) IP is `117.16.1.1`

My questions are:

1. What will be my Global Address 'To'?
2. What will be my Global Address 'From'?
3. In Destination Port "From" and "To" what do I select in the drop down list and port no for forwarding HTTP traffic (for my website)?
4. In Local Port, what do I select in drop down list and port no?

Comment: http://www.portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Dlink/GLB-802C/GLB-802Cindex.htm
not much help, but I hope you can try to DIY :)

Comment: specify your aim;i assume you want to publish the website hosted on your local machine(117.1.1.81) to be available from web(117.16.1.1) Global Address From/To: 0.0.0.0 (anybody can access site), Destination Port From: 0, Destination port To: 80/443(depending on HTTP/HTTPS), Local Port : 80/443. If you want to open All ports, use   Rule Flavour as BIMAP, IF Name: All, Local Address: 117.1.1.1, Global Address: 0.0.0.0, or from a specific public IP

Answer (score 0):

See this very detailed tutorial with screenshots :
[Port Forwarding Utorrent on the Dlink GLB-802C](http://www.portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Dlink/GLB-802C/Utorrent.htm).

Just substitute the port number 65535 in this tutorial to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link below where you can get a step-by-step guide how to do port forwarding on your D-Link GLB-802C modem.

> http://14hacking.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-i-portforward-my-d-link-glb-802c.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to forward the port 80 to the port 80 on your local IP.

e.g. 117.16.1.1:80 to 117.1.1.81:80

From 80 to port 80 on the local IP 117.1.1.81